# unable to login using myspaceid on Android browser?

Tags: php, android, myspace

I am trying to login on my website using MyspaceId running on Android web browser.  It works fine on iphone browser but fails on Android browser and following error occurs:

ErrorCode: -6
Description: The connection to the server was unsuccessful.
FailingURL:  https://secure.myspace.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=login.simpleform&featureName=openID&d=MIHfBgkrBgEEAYI3WAOggdEwgc4GCisGAQQBgjdYAwGggb8wgbwCAwIAAQICZgMCAgDABAi+cGiJgCM0cAQQqDTKk4CgnUNV0jUUBwAn8QSBkLASYTcIT/vVoNc9rfSbyRzYKg21qDUwu9ugby+cNgptULSOE/mgKGwdMHj++T7ccVyCOpdPo6bTq38vXESwl3L0aeSIi4Rj6jd0mjOfKiQFcFifjVdnF8jPHlIH5ciWiWq9AKrcDipGxhyqqkb2aufNKkuHvkf+q+Zb1x9Df2cMh2X7UhSNS2ZpJ9fkOZe+uQ==

The most strange part is that it works fine on Android if I use wifi connection. But it fails only if the wifi is disabled and network carrier connection (Edge) is enabled.

Comment: may be ur edge service provider fcuked up with https connections

Comment: I also thought that the https is causing problem and therefor I tried other https URLs, but all other URLs are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. The network provider has restricted the MySpace service. I just changed the network provider and it worked.